# Visual Studio Not Capturing Entire Line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am asking the question in MVC as that is the framework I am using for this issue, but it could be a Visual Studio issue as well.

We are using Visual Studio 2010 / MVC 4.0 for our application and all of this is while running in DEBUG mode to test the code and get it working.

I needed to add a new AccordionPanel to a section of our website.  We have about 10 total Accordion Panels on this page and all of this worked with no issue.  Between the third and fourth panel, I needed to add a new panel, so I added the below code:

`@using (Html.BeginAccordionPanel("Cancelled Reason", "pnlCancelledReason"))
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Project_View/TrackingInformation/_CancelledReason.cshtml", Model)
}`

What is happening is that this new section does not appear on the page.  What I found odd is that if I add some HTML on the end such as:

`@using (Html.BeginAccordionPanel("Cancelled Reason", "pnlCancelledReason"))
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Project_View/TrackingInformation/_CancelledReason.cshtml", Model) <b></b>
}`

and refresh the page, this new section appears until I stop debugging and restart, then it no longer appears.

What is very odd about this is:  when I step through the code and Visual Studio hits the "@Html.Partial" line, the yellow box that highlights your current row, only captures about 75% of the line above (stopping around the dR in the file name).  If I readd some HTML to that line and refresh, the yellow highlighted box for current line now captures the entire line up to the area between , but since it captured all of the relevant code, the panel appears until I stop debugging.

I can't seem to figure out what causes this?  If I copy any other panel section and paste it in the same location, the same issue occurs, so it doesn't seem to be the code, but something within Visual Studio causing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending two days on this and not sure why, but it seems if I remove the “.generated.cs” file from Visual Studio this issue goes away.  I didn’t find any articles for this, just figured ‘why the heck not’.

Sorry to have bothered you.